# java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: for jdbc connection

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc, oracle10g, database-connection

I have no idea why I am getting this error, In the program i am not accessing any array. But its still giving this error.

**java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleSql.main(OracleSql.java:1666)**

I have posted the code below.

```
public class ItT4 {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
        // loading the class
        Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");

    } catch (Exception e) {

        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}//closing main
}//closing class
```

I have set the class path required for drivers. and even gone through few links in stackoverflow.

**Modified**

I removed everything and tried printing out the s simple statement. Still i am getting the same error. The code is given below.

```
public class ItT4 {
public static void main(String[] args) {

    System.out.println("hello boss");
}
```

}

Comment: clean your project and rebulid it

Comment: Sorry, how to i do that. I am using eclipse.

Comment: It looks like you are not running your own class. Make sure your run config is right.

Comment: Now I have deleted the entire workspace, and now things are fine. I know this is not smart move. but still can you explain me what could be the possible reason. I had two more java files which uses the oracle driver, could that be the reason?.

How do i check my run configuration?

Comment: I am interested to know this solution so that the same problem does not occur in future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can follow the following process

1. click project
2. click on clean
3. select your project

Comment: Thank you, I tried that now.. but still its not working. I even created a new java file and tried printing out "hello". just hello it did not work. I even restarted eclipse. yet again its giving the same error.

Comment: @user2900314 did you rebulid the project?

Comment: I have two more java files which uses the oracle driver, could that be the reason?. should i try deleting those?

Comment: I deleted the entire workspace. I know this is not a good idea. but i had no choice.Thanks for your time.